# Image in datatable

Tags: c#, image, datatable

I read image by using OpenFileDialog. Sample code is below:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (openFileDialog1.FileName != null)
   if (picBoardImage.Image != null)
{
    picBoardImage.Image.Dispose();
}
picBoardImage.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

I want to store this image in datatable. How can I do that?

Comment: Added a link to an article for the same, check the updated answer.

Comment: You might want to add some language-related tags to this question. I would but I don't have enough magic points.

Comment: @Shamim: If the answer from Kirtan is valid accept it to mark the question as answered, if not provide mor information or close the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this -

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("ImageTable"); //Create a new DataTable instance.

DataColumn column = new DataColumn("MyImage"); //Create the column.
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"); //Type byte[] to store image bytes.
column.AllowDBNull = true;
column.Caption = "My Image";

table.Columns.Add(column); //Add the column to the table.
```

Then, add a new row to this table and set the value of the `MyImage` column.

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["MyImage"] = <Image byte array>;
tables.Rows.Add(row);
```

EDIT: You can take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx) CodeProject article for help on converting an image to a byte array.

Comment: to take image in datatable .....i need to take image in byte ...how can i do it? how can i take image in byte from openFileDialog1.

Comment: The article converts to a GIF, which is a fairly poor choice.  Among other reasons, GIFs only support 256 colors.  Luckily, this only requires changing Gif to Png in the linked code.

Comment: Byte[] Array gets displayed instead of image

Answer (score 2):

I was actually trying to accomplish this as well. My solution actually is not that involved.

```
Drawing.Bitmap img = new Drawing.Bitmap("Path to image"); //Replace string with your OpenFileDialog path.

DataColumn column = new DataColumn("ImageColumn");
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Bitmap");

//Code to add data to a cell:
DataRow row = new DataRow();
row("ImageColumn") = img;
```

For me this worked like a charm.

Comment: I tried this. It throws an error stating column Datatype is not a valid type. Can you help?

Comment: My apologies for being so very late in replying to this...do you still need help?

Comment: Thanks, John for getting back. This has been resolved.