# How do I add an image to an DataTable?

Tags: c#, image, datagrid, datatable

What I'd like to do is add a column containing an image to a DataTable. The DataTable will be given as source to a DataGrid after creating the columns/rows.

I tried the resolveUrl method and it didn't work.

Could you help me add an image column to my DataTable?

Comment: pls take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905419/image-in-datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905419/image-in-datatable)

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable("ImageTable"); //Create a new DataTable instance.

 DataColumn column = new DataColumn("MyImage"); //Create the column.
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"); //Type byte[] to store image bytes.
 column.AllowDBNull = true;
 column.Caption = "My Image";

 table.Columns.Add(column); //Add the column to the table.
```

Then you can set the MyImage column as such

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["MyImage"] = <Image byte array>;
tables.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: And how can I load my image into a byte array?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv for some sample code and tutorial

Comment: I don't quite understand how to set the link to the image from the tutorial in the link. I'd be very thankful if you could explain me. I am sorry for not being able to upvote you, as I do not have 15 reputation.